# Excel: Copy cell info based on string match from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is sort of a complex worded question, but I have created a sign-up sheet for my dorm's intramural teams, and the responses are listed on an Excel sheet with:

**Sheet 1, cell B:** Full Name

**Sheet 1, cell C:** Email Address

**Sheet 1, cell E:** The sports they wish to play on (there are four)

On sheet 2, I want to organize who and how many people want to play on each team. So I have a column for each sport, and under those are two columns (Full name and email address).

What I want to do is to parse through *Sheet 1, cell E* for each person who signed up, and if they have the instance of one of the four sports listed (Soccer, Dodgeball, Volleyball, or Bowling), add their Full name and email address under the correct column in sheet 2.

[image]

This is an image of sheet 2.

Is there a way/formula to be able to do this? Also, if the person signed up for multiple sports, they should be listed under each one. All the sports they want to play will be listed under a single cell (Sheet 1, cell E).

Comment: To make the problem easier you would probably sign up twice (or more times)...

Comment: @pnuts The signup sheet is a Google form that has checkboxes for the sports. If I were to select Soccer and Dodgeball, in the sheet 1 cell E it would say "Soccer, Dodgeball".

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, with an array formula (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)... In cell A3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$500,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A$1,Sheet1!$E$1:$E$500)),9999,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$500)),ROW()-2)),"")
```

Let me explain from the inside out...

- `ISERROR(SEARCH(A$1,Sheet1!E10))` would give us `FALSE` if the value in E10 has the name of the sport (in our header cell: `A$1`), `TRUE` otherwise
- Rather than just giving a single value, we are working on the array of cells `Sheet1!$E$1:$E$500` (which could be extended as you needed) - so this gives us an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values
- `IF(ISERROR(...),9999,ROW(...))` means that if there was not the sport we will get the value 9999, otherwise we get the row number of the cell in the array - so this gives us an array of a mix of `9999` and row numbers
- `SMALL(...,ROW()-2)` lets us pick out one of those values from the array - in this case the items in size order, and we are using `ROW()-2` as our counter (i.e. in Sheet2!A3 - `ROW()-2` is 1 and we get the smallest value from the array)... the `-2` deals with the header rows... Effectively we are indexing through a sorted list of row numbers in Sheet1 that match our condition
- `INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$500,...)` is going to give us the value from column B in Sheet1 relating to our position in the list of matching rows - i.e. the Name
- Sometimes we have our 9999 (for all the cells that didn't match the condition - these are sorted to the end of the list with `SMALL`) and so the `INDEX` will give us an error... the index is outside the range. So we can replace it with a blank.

In cell B3 we would do the same, but with `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$500,...` so that we get the email... We still need to reference `A$1` for the sport name. These two cells can then be copied across and down...

Hope this makes some sense! Good luck! And remember to enter array formulas with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>...

Comment: @g-boggs Did this work for you? Feel free to accept the answer!